# Show that if A*B*C and A*C*D, then B*C*D and A*B*D. ...With A*B*C meaning that B is between A and C...

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I need some help with this proof that i'm not shure i've covered it correctly.
It is about the position between points in a line.

The problem follows:

> Let A,B,C be points in a straight line and a,b,c their coordinates in
> that line. When the point B is between A and C, we write A*B*C or
> C*B*A. It is known that this can only happen if:
>
> $a<b<c$ or $c<b<a$
>
> Now show that if A*B*C and A*C*D, then B*C*D and A*B*D

Here is my approach to this proof:

If A*B*C and A*C*D, then:

$a<b<c$ and $a<c<d$

i. We have $b<c$ and $c<d$ that implies $b<c<d$ $\rightarrow$ B*C*D

ii. We have $a<b$ and $b<d$, that implies $a<b<d$ $\rightarrow$ A*B*D

---

I need to know if this is sufficient to prove the statement.

Comment: The problem is that you've only considered one of two cases for how to interpret A\*B\*C. You also need to show that you arrive at the same conclusion if $c < b < a.$

Comment: Oh, i see. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now you have only shown the interpretation of $A*B*C$. But you are missing one inequality- $c<b<a$.

Comment: Do tell OP(Gabriel Aparecido) if you have any query.

Comment: Also if this answer has helped you do click that saffron tick button and make it green. It means you are accepting this answer. If any other answer helped you then click that answer saffron button